# Create object and add to array of pointers - always replaces existing array

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have probably misunderstood the documentation somehow but cannot figure this out.

What I want to do, is to be able to create a new `ClientContact` and save it to an array of pointers called `contacts` in `Clients` table.

This is the relevant code:

```
var Client = Parse.Object.extend("Client");
var selectedClient = new Client();
// sets the objectId based on URL params
selectedClient.id = $routeSegment.$routeParams.id;

var ClientContact = Parse.Object.extend("ClientContact");
var contact = new ClientContact();
contact.set('name', 'test');
contact.set('desc', 'some description');
contact.set('phoneNumber', '123');

selectedClient.add('contacts', contact);
selectedClient.save().then(function() {
    console.log('saved');
}, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

As expected, the `contact` is automatically saved and added to `contacts` when the `selectedClient` is saved.

But if I run the same code again (in the testing this means refreshing the page), a new `ClientContact` is saved but it replaces the `contacts` array entirely.

That is, only the most recent `ClientContact` is associated to the `Client`, any new additions replaces the array, leaving only one pointer.

I hope there is an obvious an easy fix that I have simply failed to spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems I have located the problem.

I was assuming that array operations on an object was independant on the local representation.

What I did above was to construct an object based on a known objectId:

```
var Client = Parse.Object.extend("Client");
var selectedClient = new Client();
// sets the objectId based on URL params
selectedClient.id = $routeSegment.$routeParams.id;
```

Turns out that array operations like `add` and `remove` are performed based on the local information. So doing the above construction leaves my array, in the selectedClient object, empty at each page refresh. This was the cause of my array being replaced with a new single valued array.

In short, one should fetch an object before performing array operations it seems.

The reason for the construction above was to avoid having to re-query the Client object when navigating around an AngularJS based webpage. The solution was fortunately simple: loading the Client object once in a parent scope. 
This moves outside the scope of the question. Just wanted to mention that as well.